# JavaScript variable changing between two values on a regular basis

Tags: javascript, variables, timeout, intervals

I want a variable's value regularly changing between 0 and 1.  If I have a variable whose value is 0 (`counter = 0`), how can I increase it by 1 (`counter = 1`) after a few seconds, then decrease it back to 0 ( `counter = 0`) after another few seconds? An endless loop basically is what I want.

I'm assuming this will require setTimeout or setInterval, but I've absolutely no idea how I'd go about this. I'm very unfamiliar with the syntax; I'm very much a newbie. Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/xPPOKa?editors=1010?

Comment: so many answers, not one uses the simplest method for this ... `counter = 1 - counter` - no need for `? :` or `if` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using now =D

Comment: @PauloDiogo - thief!!! :p kidding :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it's for a good reason! haha thx man XD

Answer (score 1):

You can create an endless, timed loop by having a function that calls itself at the end via setTimeout.  See below.

```js
var count = 0;
function flip() {
  count = Number(!count);
  console.log(count);
  setTimeout(flip, 1000);
}

flip();
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach:

```
// possible addition: allow user to stop the timer
const rotate = (time, vals) => {
  // TODO: handle incorrect vals (non-empty array) or time (positive number)
  let idx = 0;
  setInterval(() => idx = (idx + 1) % vals.length, time);
  return {
    get val() {return vals[idx];}
  }
}

const toggle = rotate(1000, [0, 1])

toggle.val //=> depends on when you call it, changes every 1000 ms
           //   but always either 0 or 1.
```

One advantage of this is that it doesn't keep the value in global scope where someone else can mess with it, but encapsulates it in a closure.

It's more generic because you can easily change the time between updates and you can choose whatever you want for values (for example, `rotate(5000, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz')`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;
var changeCounter = function () {
  counter = counter === 0 ? 1 : 0;
  console.log('counter', counter);
  setTimeout(changeCounter, 1000);
}
changeCounter();
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework but try this:

```
var value = 0;

setInterval(
  function() {
    value = value===0 ? 1 : 0;
    console.log('value =', value);
  },
  1000
);
```

`setInterval` will call the function over and over again without needing to call `setTimeout` over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is what you want, as documented in [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), you should pass a function and a time interval in milliseconds on how often to execute the code.

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 

  counter = 1 - counter;

  //Do what you want with the result...
  //alert(counter);  

}, 1000);
```

https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/xPPOKa?editors=1010

Not using global variable...
https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/KyyMXZ